# Makefile For Loop Pattern Substitution

Tags: makefile

In the following makefile for loop, how can I edit the string, that the i variable represents, with a pattern substitution in the middle of the string? In my case, I wish to replace any / character in the string with a _ character.

```
for i in $(MODULES:%.cpp=%); do \
    g++ -c Sources/$$i.cpp -o Build/$$i.o; \
done
```

For example if MODULES = Directory/File.cpp then the inner line should expand to

```
g++ -c Sources/Directory/File.cpp -o Build/Directory_File.o
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is valid only with GNU make and bash.

Simple bash substitution (`${parameter/pattern/string}`) in the context of a make recipe (double `$`):

```
for i in $(MODULES:%.cpp=%); do \
    g++ -c Sources/$$i.cpp -o Build/$${i//\//_}.o; \
done
```

Warning: this works only if the shell used by make is bash. So, add maybe a:

```
SHELL := bash
```

at the beginning of your Makefile.

Explanation:

- `${i/X/_}` expands as the value of variable `i` in which the first occurrence of `X` is replaced by `_`.
- `${i//X/_}` expands as the value of variable `i` in which all occurrences of `X` are replaced by `_`.
- In your case `X` is the `/` character and it must be escaped (`\/`): `${i//\//_}`.

Note that there is probably a less bash and more make way to do the same. Something like:

```
SRCS := $(shell find Sources -type f -name *.cpp)
OBJS :=

define OBJ_rule
obj := Build/$$(subst /,_,$$(patsubst Sources/%.cpp,%,$(1))).o
OBJS += $$(obj)
$$(obj): $(1)
    g++ -c $$< -o $$@
endef
$(foreach s,$(SRCS),$(eval $(call OBJ_rule,$(s))))

.PHONY: objs

objs: $(OBJS)
```

Which instantiates one rule per module and should do the same... with the significant advantage that, when you type `make objs`, only the outdated object files are rebuilt. But it's a bit more tricky.